# Facebook Sign up and JSF

Tags: facebook, jsf-2, primefaces

In my netbeans 7.2 . I am using JSF Primefaces 3.5 and i am trying to add the facebook sign up in the application but i got an error saying that "The entity name must be immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference"

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration?
                        client_id=113869198637480&
                        redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Ftools%2Fecho%2F&
                        fields=name,birthday,gender,location,email"
                        scrolling="auto"
                        frameborder="no"
                        style="border:none"
                        allowTransparency="true"
                        width="100%"
                        height="330">

                </iframe>
```

I just followed how facebook did .. please help ... thanks ... Beginner here ...

Comment: You can't use & sign in xhtml, try &amp; instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, you can't use & directly in xhtml, you need html entites like &.